# Calling Data from Named Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, database, sorting

I'm using python and I'm trying to call and plot arrays from a data set. The data set is named and they data is in the format:

```
"{'err': array([8.,8.,8.,....],dtype=float32), 'saa': 
array([239.93,242.02,242.28,...], dtype=float32)}"
```

There are multiple datasets in the array.  I'm trying to call them one by one.

If you care how I formatted said arrays, they were formatted with the following code:

```
rows=[{'amf':amf,'err':err,'unc':unc,'saa':saa,'time':time,'o3':o3,'sza':sza}]
with open(outfile, 'a') as f:
    writer.writerow(rows)
```

---

As requested, here is hypothetical plotting code:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)

inputfile = '/usr2/..../..../file'
data = np.genfromtxt(inputfile,delimiter = '\t')
```

Honestly, not sure where to go from here to call the list, but I would like to get an output of being able to call a single array at a time like so:

```
output from calling single array function:
[8., 8., 8.,....... 8., 8., 8.,]
```

I'd also like to be able to plot one array against another. I'm just unsure how to call each array individually.

Comment: Do you have a dictionary of arrays? What are you actually trying to do. Show your hypothetical plotting code.

Comment: Also, have you considered using pandas?

Comment: I have not, I'm honestly not too familiar with pandas applications at this point.

Comment: I'm editing with hypothetical plotting code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to convert a string that has the format of a dictionary into a dictionary that you can call. Something you can do is use exec()
function in the form of:

```
code_to_run = 'my_dict_name = ' + my_dictionary
exec(code_to_run)

for key, val in my_dict_name.items():
    # Do whatever you want...
```

What this will do is create a full string of code in which you will execute using exec(). You will then be able to call my_dict_name as if it were a dictionary.

Hope this helps,
Ethan

Comment: Thank you! I'll get back to this with my solution.